# ReflectionException: Class StripeBilling does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to implement a Billing interface which uses Stripe.
I have created the Billing interface, Stripe class and binded the interface using a Service Provider.

I receive a Class not found error when trying to run the code:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 737: Class
>   Acme\Billing\StripeBilling does not exist

I can't figure out what the issue is, I've double checked for small issues like correct case etc.

Here is the code I've used:

**app/Acme/Billing/BillingInterface.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\Billing;

interface BillingInterface {
    public function charge(array $data);
}
```

**app/Acme/Billing/StripeBilling.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\Billing;

use Stripe;
use Stripe_Charge;
use Stripe_Customer;
use Stripe_InvalidRequestError;
use Stripe_CardError;
use Exception;

class StripeBilling implements BillingInterface {

    public function __construct()
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'))
    }

    public function charge(array $data)
    {

        try
        {
            return Stripe_Charge::create([
                'amount' => 1000, // £10
                'currency' => 'gbp',
                'description' => $data['email'],
                'card' => $data['token']
            ]);
        } 

        catch(Stripe_CardError $e)
        {
            dd('card was declined');

        }

    }
}
```

**app/Providers/BillingServiceProvider.php (UPDATED)**

```
class BillingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Billing\BillingInterface', 'Billing\StripeBilling');
    }
}
```

**BasketController.php (ADDED)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $billing = \App::make('Billing\BillingInterface');
    return $billing->charge([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'stripe-token' => $request->token,
    ]);
```

I have added `App\Providers\BillingServiceProvider::class` to my `app.php` file, and updated my composer.json to include Acme folder `"Acme\\": "app/"`

Comment: PSR-0 or PSR-4? If PSR-4, then the path is wrong. PSR-4 deletes the prefix from the class name, the remainder is transformed into a path - so there is no "Acme" part in the search path, but in your path it is.

Comment: I am using PSR-4; Changing the binding in my Provider like `$this->app->bind('Billing\BillingInterface', 'Billing\StripeBilling');` returns a `Class Acme\Billing\BillingInterface does not exist` instead

Comment: Please check updated question, after changing the code as shown I'm still getting the original error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks two-fold:

1. The PSR-4 autoload definition in your `composer.json` file is incorrect.

   If your Acme folder lives inside the app folder, e.g. `/dir/project_root/app/Acme/Billing/BillingInterface.php`, then your composer.json definition should look like this:

   ```
   "psr-4": {
     "Acme\\": "app/Acme" 
   }
   ```

   This is the root cause of the error you are receiving, which is not a Laravel-specific error. The autoloader simply cannot find the class you are asking for, even though the requested fully qualified class name is correct.
2. Your interface and class are not bound to the container properly (missing the `Acme` portion of the namespace).

   Because you've defined both of them in the `Acme` namespace, you need to ensure Acme is present in your service provider definitions. So your service provider should look like this:

   ```
   class BillingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       public function register()
       {
           $this->app->bind('Acme\Billing\BillingInterface', 'Acme\Billing\StripeBilling');
       }
   }
   ```

   (Or, better yet, use the `::class` syntax for improved IDE support.)

   You will also need to make sure the fully qualified classname is correct when requesting the class in your controller: `App::make('Acme\Billing\BillingInterface')`. (I would recommend using dependency injection instead of this syntax, anyway.)

Comment: I have correct the path in my composer.json but is it weird that `$this->app->bind('Acme\Billing\BillingInterface', 'Acme\Billing\StripeBilling');` doesn't work but `$this->app->bind('Billing\BillingInterface', 'Acme\Billing\StripeBilling');` does? I get BillingInterface not found.

Comment: You are probably requesting the incorrect namespace from wherever you are trying to inject the Billing service (like a controller or another service). Make sure that anywhere you are utilizing the BillingInterface or StripeBilling implementation, you are using the full, proper namespace (e.g. `Acme\Billing\BillingInterface`).

Comment: Thanks Cryode, not that it will stop me from marking this as the answer, but could you give me an example of how I would use dependency injection?

Comment: [Laravel has documentation on that.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)